# how openstacksdk get_port just through ip_address

Tags: port, openstack, openstack-neutron, openstacksdk

How to get the special port information which only dependent on the `ip-address` field by `openstacksdk` API, like the result as the `openstack-client` tool show:

```
# openstack port list --fixed-ip ip-address=1.1.1.1
+-----+------+-------------+---------------------------------------+--------+
| ID  | Name | MAC Address | Fixed IP Addresses                    | Status |
+-----+------+-------------+---------------------------------------+--------+
| f23 |      | fa:*****:ad | ip_address='1.1.1.1', subnet_id='821' | ACTIVE |
+-----+------+-------------+---------------------------------------+--------+
```

I had try these methods, none work:

- `port = conn.network.get_port(openstack.network.v2.port.Port(fixed_ips=[{'subnet_id'" '821', 'ip_address': '1.1.1.1'}]))`
- err: `openstack.exceptions.InvalidRequest: Request requires an ID but none was found`

---

- `port = conn.network.ports(fixed_ips=[{'ip_address': '1.1.1.1'}])`
- err: `openstack.exceptions.BadRequestException: BadRequestException: 400: Client Error for url: domain:9696/v2.0/ports?fixed_ips=ip_address, Invalid input for operation: 'ip_address' is not of the form <key>=[value].`

---

- `port = conn.network.ports(fixed_ips=['1.1.1.1'])`
- err: `penstack.exceptions.BadRequestException: BadRequestException: 400: Client Error for url: domain:9696/v2.0/ports?fixed_ips=1.1.1.1, Invalid input for operation: '1.1.1.1' is not of the form <key>=[value].`

---

- `port = conn.network.ports(ip_address='1.1.1.1')`
- err: `openstack.exceptions.BadRequestException: BadRequestException: 400: Client Error for url: https://gzi-ost.2980.com:9696/v2.0/ports?ip_address=1.1.1.1, ['ip_address'] is invalid attribute for filtering`

Refer to these documentation: [**network.port-operations**](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/network.html#port-operations) and **[openstack api list-ports-detail](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/network/v2/index.html?expanded=list-ports-detail)** .

How could I achieve that? Thank you in advance.

One more thing,  I couldn't know the `port_id` before, only know the fixed `ip-address`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, my bad, the problem is that my request parameter has a wrong format data.

Solve it by `import urllib` to encode the request json data in **Python 3**.

- `conn.network.ports(fixed_ips=urllib.parse.urlencode({'ip_address': '1.1.1.1'}))`
- - [Returns: A generator of port objects.](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/network.html#port-operations#ports)

or

- `conn.list_ports({'fixed_ips': urllib.parse.urlencode({'ip_address': '1.1.1.1'})})`
- - [Returns: A list of port munch.Munch.](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/connection.html#openstack.connection.Connection.list_ports)